# SQL remove whitespace in query without the trim function in MS SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have

```
Concat(L.LOT,L.PLAN_DESC,L.PLAN_NO) as Lot_Plan,
```

as part of my query but it results in

```
2    RP741755
```

where I need

```
2RP741755
```

Usually `trim(Concat(L.LOT,L.PLAN_DESC,L.PLAN_NO)) as Lot_Plan,`would work but I get

```
Msg 195, Level 15, State 10, Line 8
'trim' is not a recognized built-in function name.
```

I have also tried it just as L.LOT+L.PLAN_DESC+L.PLAN_NO but I get the same issue.

Comment: Just found the answer - (Concat(rtrim(L.LOT),rtrim(L.PLAN_DESC),rtrim(L.PLAN_NO))) as Lot_Plan,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You seem to want:

```
concat(ltrim(rtrim(L.LOT)), L.PLAN_DESC, L.PLAN_NO) as Lot_Plan,
```

SQL Server didn't have `trim()` for a long time, but it has `ltrim()` and `rtrim()`.  [`trim()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) was introduced in SQL Server 2017, but sadly without the functionality in the ISO/ANSI version.

Comment: TSQL does have TRIM() in [current versions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/trim-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). Progress comes slowly!